# I can't get files from gcloud app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud

I've created a project on google cloud, and deployed the app with `gcloud app deploy` command, and I can see the app when I run `gcloud app browse` command on myapp.appspot.com
Now I am on another computer, I want to get the files from the cloud, so I can continue working on them. 
I use the command `appcfg.py -A myprojectid -V version download_app output_folder/`
The result is:

```
06:00 AM Host: appengine.google.com
06:00 AM Fetching file list...
06:00 AM Fetching files...
```

and it stops there and there are no files in the output folder.
So, where are my files and how do I get them?

(I get my projectid and version from google cloud console)

(This is a php project)

Comment: I can't repro, I'm able to download mine  (python) just fine. Side note: for the future you may want to revisit your version control strategy...

Comment: Actually, I didn't even have a strategy yet, I just deployed a code, and now want to clone it to another computer.

Comment: In the developer console `App Engine` -> `Settings` there is a `Permanently prohibit code downloads` config, was it did ever set for your app?

Comment: More of a workaround if you're really stuck as it's rather tedious if your have many files: In the `App Engine` -> `Versions` table there is a `Diagnose` column with a `Tools` dropdown and a `Source` menu under it, which gets you to the `StackDriver Debug` where, at least for my app, I can see the uploaded files and their content.

Comment: @DanCornilescu, thanks for the workarounds, my workaround was simpler, I moved from Google Cloud for now until they have better documentation :)

Comment: That works too :)